# Is tension caused when modulating away from the tonic note?

Tags: theory

And if so, the further you modulate away from it, the greater the tension?

If the tonic note is C, would be the furthest modulation be, B natural, according to the overtone series

Comment: Not necessarily. From key C, a modulation into Dm, Em, F, G, Am - there's possibly no tension created at all. Other keys - it depends *how* that modulation occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is tension caused when modulating away from the tonic note?

If you see modulation as movement of tonic, then the only way to move the tonic somewhere is, away from where it used to be. If you move something, it moves away from its previous location.

I don't feel the movement of tonic as any kind of *tension* at all. **Tension means a sense of pressure, *waiting* for release, so you could be at rest.** Tonic is your home. When tonic moves, your home moves away and you forget the old home very quickly. **Modulation does not create a sense of pressure and waiting for something to happen.** If you want to go back to the original key, it can only happen while you still remember the old key, and that doesn't last many seconds. Modulations make me want to *look forward* instead, "oh, a new fresh place, what can I do here", not look back.

I would describe the sensation of modulation as *reorientation* and *settling down*. Not tension. Tension is not caused by modulation, and the length of movement has no effect on the amount of tension, because there is no tension.

What *does* create tension is when you have a sense of where tonic is, but when the harmony is not in that position. That is, when e.g. C major has been established as tonic (this can be done by playing a *cadence* like C - F - G7 - C), but when you're not hearing the tonic chord. When you know C is tonic and you hear a G7 chord, you know you're not home, you're eagerly waiting to get home. And then, when the C chord finally comes, the tension is released. Harmonic position is like leaning to some direction. Your *feet* are at tonic, but you're bent over ... and that's harmonic tension. When the tonic chord comes, you get back straight up. But *modulation* means moving your feet, your balance spot. When you get straight up in the new place, you're at rest again, no tension, you're just in a different place.

Comment: I agree with you that when I am at home there is no tension ;)

Answer (score 2):

I see at least three ways of thinking about this question, depending on what is meant by "tension."

(1) On the one hand, there's some idea of tension created by the fact that we're no longer in the tonic key.  Sometimes the word tension is invoked to describe the idea that hanging out on a V (or particularly a V7) chord for a while makes one anticipate a resolution to tonic.  However, even in that simple case, the "tension" is usually not created by simply moving to a dominant harmony, but rather by composers using delaying tactics before finally resolving to I.  Thus, it's not the motion *away* from tonic that creates the tension, but rather the *delayed return* to tonic that can feel tense.  Perhaps a very minor amount of tension for resolution to I would be created by moving quickly between I-V-I, but it's only created by things like having a leading tone in the V chord that should resolve, not simply by the motion away from tonic in the first place.

With that in mind, it's easy to see why modulations create even less tension.  Take the simple modulation to V to begin with.  Normally, tension for resolution exists with a V chord, because it has a leading tone (and perhaps a tritone if it is V7).  But when one actually modulates to the key of V, the tritone will no longer be present.  Instead, V gets its own leading tone, and the motion to V begins to feel like the temporary "home."  As piiperi notes, even staying in a new key for a few seconds begins to downplay that feeling of tension about the leading tone to I.  It's now the third of the "temporary home" chord, which has its own leading tone.  By the time one moves through another phrase or two, any sense of the "original leading tone must resolve to I!" sensation has likely decayed enough that there's little "tension" left.

(2) That's not to say that one can't have a different sort of feeling of tension from modulation created by *formal expectation*.  For the simplest example, a common period structure often cadences to V at the end of the first phrase.  It may simply be a half cadence, or it may be a full PAC in the key of V, in which case it may feel like a modulation.  But if one listens to a lot of period structures, one develops an expectation that it's likely that V will return back to I by the end of the second phrase.  I suppose one might call that a feeling of "tension," but it's not very strong, as modulating periods exist as well which never return back to the opening tonic (and we don't generally find them too jarring).

Similarly, short forms like song forms often will have a temporary modulation during a bridge section or some other contrasting portion.  If the song is following pretty regular 4-bar or 8-bar phrases and seems to be a standard "song form," then we may expect that any modulation in a bridge is likely temporary and will tend to resolve back to tonic within a phrase or two.  In this way, we may have a feeling of a sort of "tension" that lasts a bit longer than the few seconds piiperi mentioned, perhaps extending for a couple phrases.

But this sensation doesn't last long.  If the composition doesn't conform to those standard forms like period structure or simple song forms, and instead decides to extend the modulation and stay in the new key, listeners will rapidly begin to reorient themselves and lose any sensation of a "need to resolve" (tension?) that wants to go back to the home key.  There have been several studies attempting to measure this effect by seeing whether listeners care if a long classical movement actually ends in the key it began in -- and they basically concluded that even trained listeners don't notice.  Subtle modulations that cause the final key to be different from the opening key won't often be noticed, unless a trained listener is spending all the time paying strict attention to the harmony and trying to track what the local key is.  (Or, obviously, unless someone has perfect pitch.)

That task of tracking keys is so intensive that even trained listeners can't usually do it for a long time through lots of modulations without effort, and there's no proof of a lingering sense of "tension" if a sonata form movement just happens not to end in the key that it began in.

So, once again, there may be some tension created by a need for "formal resolution," but only on a relatively local level.  Once a piece stays in a key for more than a couple phrases and/or lacks the standard form structures that would create a sense of a need to return to I at a particular time, any sense of tension goes away.

(3) Lastly, there is I suppose a kind of "tension" created by a surprising modulation.  The listener perhaps perks up and thinks, "What the heck just happened!?"  I don't know if the question is trying to get at this, as it's a quite different sensation from cases (1) and (2).  And such an effect usually depends on the smoothness of the transition and modulation, rather than the remoteness of the key.  If one simply starts new music in a completely different key, it will likely be surprising or disruptive (tense?) regardless of whether the new key is relatively closely related to tonic or much more "distant."  (Exceptions may be stereotypical moves to dominant or relative major/minor, etc.  But sudden jumps to other keys or even a sudden motion to dominant in the middle of a phrase with no preparation might sound "off.")

On the other hand, a modulation to a distant key can often be accomplished quite smoothly with appropriate techniques.  There are easy ways to modulate from C to B, for example, with only a few chords and without creating too much harmonic disruption.  The same is true of any other "distant" key, even F#.  Any "tension" due to surprise will be a function of how the modulation is handled and its abruptness, rather than the tonal "distance" traveled.  (And obviously this sort of "tension" -- if one wants to call it that -- tends to fade quite quickly, as expectations of the new key take over.)

---

Now, to address the question more directly -- do any of these different types of "tension" vary depending on how "distant" the new key is?

In case (1), a distant key might actually undermine the sense of tension, depending on what key one goes to.  The immediate need to "resolution" often comes from continuing to feel a need for reorientation, e.g., for the original leading tone to resolve.  Moving to a completely foreign key will more quickly destroy the sense of original function to scale degrees, thereby causing any tension to "resolve" to tonic to decrease rapidly.  More stereotypical modulations to close keys (V, IV, vi, etc.) might be able to maintain a sense of local key around the tonic for longer.

The situation is similar in case (2), as in that case tension is only maintained by common formal expectations.  Modulations to distant keys don't generally carry as many formal expectations about when (or if) they may "resolve" back to tonic, so case (2) probably only has tension *at all* if one is in a relatively close key to tonic, which has a standard pathway back.

Case (3) is the only place where perhaps there's more tension created by the "What the heck?!" factor when one moves to distant keys.  But, as mentioned above, that also depends greatly on how the modulation is handled.  A smooth modulation (even to a remote key) might almost be unnoticed except by listeners really paying attention, while an abrupt jump could be disruptive regardless.  Nevertheless, it's perhaps a bit more likely that moves to distant keys will often feel less expected.

Answer (score 0):

Very often you use  the  secondary dominant (V7) to modulate to another key (if you don't directly modulate as e.g. from C to G,  or C to F by dominant or subdominant relationship or relative and  parallel keys).

Now you can say the not-common tones of the leaving key and this dominant of the new key are creating a tension, so modulating from C to B is very rarely and the (V7) is F#7 while the modulation from C to Db mostly uses Ab7 (the mediant of C major with a common tone = C).

Without controlling all modulations I'd say to all others you can use a direct modulation where you have at least one common tone (relative and parallel keys 2 common tones).

The furthest modulation would be changing directly from C to F#.  I think this tritonus-distance will create the similar tension like the modulation to B via F#.

In my ear the modulations to the mediant keys sounds softer  than the modulation to a parallel key ("Querstand"). But this impression might be very personally and individual like your entire question may be opinion based.

With other words: I would agree with your question:

> Is tension caused when modulating away from the tonic note?

and only partial with your conclusion:

> And if so, the further you modulate away from it, the greater the tension?

under the restrictions mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I think your terms are a bit muddled.   Tension is related to, pulls towards, a home note or chord.   Modulation sets up a new home.  Tension is now satisfied by returning THERE, not to the previous home.   (And that's a pretty good definition for 'have we modulated, or are we just visiting?')

Then, there are degrees of remoteness and degrees of tension.   The furthest we can get from C is, I suppose, F♯.   Play a C major chord then F♯major.  Remote?  Certainly.  Tension?  Maybe not as much as I feel from a G7, or an intensified G7+5. F♯ is a waypoint on an interesting excursion.  G7+5 really PULLS towards C though.  Magnetism is stronger when the objects get closer...

Play, hear and understand the concepts I've talked about.  Probably sticking neat labels on things will feel less important.  I hope so!

Comment: I find the C-F# chord transition to be more tense than the C-G7 one. C-G7 sounds typical and blasé. C-F# sounds like a completely alien chord has barged in. Heck, the G7 chord in a C-F#-G7 chord progression feels like a sigh of relief.

Comment: Definitions of 'tension'.   Degree of alienation?  Or a specific pull in a specific direction?